# Merchant initiated transactions fail using stored payment method in cybersource

Tags: c#, payment-gateway, google-pay, recurring-billing, cybersource

I am using CyberSource and here is what I am trying to do:

1. make payment with PAN (customer initialed transaction)
2. store payment for future use
3. use stored payment method for merchant initiated transactions

Documentation I used: https://developer.cybersource.com/docs/cybs/en-us/payments/developer/ctv/rest/payments/credentials-processsing-intro/credentials-mit-recur-intro.html. Particularly looking at following sections of the documentation:

1. Initial CIT Recurring Payment with a PAN
2. Subsequent MIT Recurring Payments

I believe, I follow documentation closely, however, the result that I get is not ideal. First transaction is successful, and it looks like payment method is stored on file. However, following merchant initiated transactions fail with following error: `The credit card number is either missing or invalid`

Below is my implementation, I am using C# and CyberSource's SDK. I would appreciate any help, thanks you in advance!

CIT (first transaction)

```
 string clientReferenceInformationCode = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            Ptsv2paymentsClientReferenceInformation clientReferenceInformation = new Ptsv2paymentsClientReferenceInformation(
                Code: clientReferenceInformationCode
           );
            bool processingInformationCapture = true;
            string processingInformationPaymentSolution = "012";

            Ptsv2paymentsProcessingInformation processingInformation = new Ptsv2paymentsProcessingInformation(
                Capture: processingInformationCapture,
                PaymentSolution: processingInformationPaymentSolution,
                AuthorizationOptions: new Ptsv2paymentsProcessingInformationAuthorizationOptions
                {
                    Initiator = new Ptsv2paymentsProcessingInformationAuthorizationOptionsInitiator
                    {
                        CredentialStoredOnFile = true,
                        Type = "customer"
                    },

                },
                CommerceIndicator: "internet"
                , RecurringOptions: new Ptsv2paymentsProcessingInformationRecurringOptions
                {
                    FirstRecurringPayment = true
                }
           ) ;

            Ptsv2paymentsPaymentInformation paymentInformation = new Ptsv2paymentsPaymentInformation(
                FluidData: new Ptsv2paymentsPaymentInformationFluidData
                {
                    Value = googlePayToken,
                }
           );

            string orderInformationAmountDetailsTotalAmount = "1";
            string orderInformationAmountDetailsCurrency = "USD";
            Ptsv2paymentsOrderInformationAmountDetails orderInformationAmountDetails = new Ptsv2paymentsOrderInformationAmountDetails(
                TotalAmount: orderInformationAmountDetailsTotalAmount,
                Currency: orderInformationAmountDetailsCurrency
           );

            string orderInformationBillToFirstName = "John";
            string orderInformationBillToLastName = "Deo";
            string orderInformationBillToAddress1 = "901 Metro Center Blvd";
            string orderInformationBillToLocality = "Foster City";
            string orderInformationBillToAdministrativeArea = "CA";
            string orderInformationBillToPostalCode = "94404";
            string orderInformationBillToCountry = "US";
            string orderInformationBillToEmail = "test@googlepay.com";
            string orderInformationBillToPhoneNumber = "6504327113";

            Ptsv2paymentsOrderInformationBillTo orderInformationBillTo = new Ptsv2paymentsOrderInformationBillTo(
                FirstName: orderInformationBillToFirstName,
                LastName: orderInformationBillToLastName,
                Address1: orderInformationBillToAddress1,
                Locality: orderInformationBillToLocality,
                AdministrativeArea: orderInformationBillToAdministrativeArea,
                PostalCode: orderInformationBillToPostalCode,
                Country: orderInformationBillToCountry,
                Email: orderInformationBillToEmail,
                PhoneNumber: orderInformationBillToPhoneNumber
           );

            Ptsv2paymentsOrderInformation orderInformation = new Ptsv2paymentsOrderInformation(
                AmountDetails: orderInformationAmountDetails,
                BillTo: orderInformationBillTo
           );

            var requestObj = new CreatePaymentRequest(
                ClientReferenceInformation: clientReferenceInformation,
                ProcessingInformation: processingInformation,
                PaymentInformation: paymentInformation,
                OrderInformation: orderInformation
           );

            try
            {
                var configDictionary = new Configuration().GetConfiguration();
                var clientConfig = new CyberSource.Client.Configuration(merchConfigDictObj: configDictionary);

                var apiInstance = new PaymentsApi(clientConfig);
                PtsV2PaymentsPost201Response result = apiInstance.CreatePayment(requestObj);

                Console.WriteLine(result);
                return result;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception on calling the API : " + e.Message);
                return null;
            }
```

Following MITs:

```
Ptsv2paymentsProcessingInformation processingInformation = new Ptsv2paymentsProcessingInformation(
                AuthorizationOptions: new Ptsv2paymentsProcessingInformationAuthorizationOptions
                {
                    Initiator = new Ptsv2paymentsProcessingInformationAuthorizationOptionsInitiator
                    {
                        StoredCredentialUsed = true,
                        Type = "merchant",
                        MerchantInitiatedTransaction = new Ptsv2paymentsProcessingInformationAuthorizationOptionsInitiatorMerchantInitiatedTransaction
                        {
                            Reason = "7",
                            PreviousTransactionId = transactionId,
                        }
                    },
                },
                CommerceIndicator: "recurring",
                Capture: true
           );

            

            Ptsv2paymentsPaymentInformation paymentInformation = new Ptsv2paymentsPaymentInformation(
               Card: new Ptsv2paymentsPaymentInformationCard
               {
                   ExpirationYear = card.ExpirationYear,
                   ExpirationMonth = card.ExpirationMonth,
                   Number = card.Prefix + "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
               }

           );


            string clientReferenceInformationCode = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            Ptsv2paymentsClientReferenceInformation clientReferenceInformation = new Ptsv2paymentsClientReferenceInformation(
                Code: clientReferenceInformationCode
           );

            var requestObj = new CreatePaymentRequest(
               ClientReferenceInformation: clientReferenceInformation,
               ProcessingInformation: processingInformation,
               OrderInformation: orderInformation,
               PaymentInformation: paymentInformation
            );

            PtsV2PaymentsPost201Response result = apiInstance.CreatePayment(requestObj);
```

Comment: did you reach out to the cybersource support to ask why the transaction failed? also, I believe cybersource needs to tell you if you really need to encrypt the Google Pay token on your side.

Comment: I have reached out to them but haven't heard anything from them for now. According to the documentation, I need to encrypt the token on client side like this `window.btoa(googlePayToken)`, and I have implemented this piece of code.

Comment: the documentation is not very clear on what you need to send for merchant initiated transactions if it comes to Google Pay. I believe you have to wait for an answer from cybersource.